# GeoPDF with higher detail when zooming in in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geopdf

In QGIS 3 there is a bult-in utility to create GeoPDFs but it has a limitation of 3000PPP max (resolution).

[image]

So when I open the GeoPDF everything seems fine:

[image]

But when I zoom in, the strokes are so wide that I can barely see anything....

[image]

Is there a way in QGIS 3 to build the GeoPDF so that when I zoom in I can see everything with a much higher detail?

Breaking the 3000PPP max. resolution limitation should be a solution I guess but I am not sure if it's possible...

Comment: You can reduce the stroke width? Or increase the scale?

Comment: @Erik The resolution field sets how much you can zoom in without loosing details. The higher the resolution (PPP) the thinner the stroke when you zoom in. But I can't set a higher resolution than 3000PPP, it is capped...

Comment: @Egidi, no the resolution and the stroke thinness are not linked but as you zoom out really thin stroke stay a last one pixel wide to be displayed (because one pixel wide i's the thinnest thing a screen could display) when you zoom in the stroke stay one pixel wide untill you exceed the image resolution then it become wider. Anyway resolution only mater for image format, if you export in vector format (and QGIS is able to export  vector PDF) resolution is meaningless and you just need to set thinner stroke

Comment: @J.R thanks for your comment, that really helped. Just getting the stroke thinner solved the problem. Can you post an answer so that I can accept it for future visitors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the resolution and the stroke thinness are not linked but as you zoom-out really thin stroke stay at last one pixel wide to be displayed (because one pixel wide i's the thinnest thing a screen could display) when you zoom-in the stroke stay one pixel wide untill you exceed the image resolution then it become wider.

Anyway resolution only mater for image format, if you export in vector format (and QGIS is able to export vector PDF) resolution is meaningless and you just need to set a thinner stroke